# Change Default Directory to Open while Opening File Explorer

Tags: files, filemanager

Suppose I want the file explorer to open Desktop instead of home how do i set it up so that my default directory while opening file explorer is Desktop instead of Home

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: Thank you It Answered the question